# How to read 資格外活動許可?

Tags: kanji, compounds

I know 資格 is しかく, 活動 is かつどう and 許可 is きょか, but the 外 puzzles me here. Is it just がい？

Comment: [資格外活動許可申請書](http://ja.forvo.com/word/資格外活動許可申請書/) I can't have this to work on my computer but maybe it can solve your question.

Comment: How about http://www.clair.or.jp/tagengorev/eja/e/01-1-2.pdf or http://www.osaka-livinginfo.jp/jp/immigration/020/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, しかくがいかつどうきょか.

[An agreeing source (via pronunciation)](http://forvo.com/word/%E8%B3%87%E6%A0%BC%E5%A4%96%E6%B4%BB%E5%8B%95%E8%A8%B1%E5%8F%AF%E7%94%B3%E8%AB%8B%E6%9B%B8/)

Edit: hah i'm too late.  The same source is cited in the comments before me.